# $\mathcal{O}_K/p\mathcal{O}_K$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/p\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ for some $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, $p$ a prime number and $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$. Consider the homomorphism $$\psi : \frac{\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]}{p\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]} \rightarrow \frac{\mathcal{O}_K}{p\mathcal{O}_K}$$
When $p \not\mid[ \mathcal{O}_K : \mathbb{Z}[\alpha] ]$, we can prove that $\psi$ is actually an isomorphism, so we understand $\mathcal{O}_K/p\mathcal{O}_K$ reasonably well and can apply Dedekind's theorem to find the prime ideals above $p$.

My question is: can we always find such an $\alpha$? Otherwise stated, can we always find an $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$ such that $p \not\mid[ \mathcal{O}_K : \mathbb{Z}[\alpha] ]$?

According to Keith Conrad in [this paper](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/dedekindf.pdf), it's not the case (page 5, second to last paragraph). But he doesn't give a specific counterexample. If anyone knew one or could point me to a reference I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard example is $K =\mathbb Q(\beta)$ where $\beta$ is a root of $f(X) = X^3+X^2-2X+8$, and $p=2$.

One can check using Hensel's lemma that $f$ has three distinct roots in $\mathbb Z_2$, and hence $2$ splits completely in $\mathcal O_K$.

On the other hand, suppose there exists some $\alpha$ with $p\nmid [\mathcal O_K:\mathbb Z[\alpha]]$. Let $g$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. In order for $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ to have finite index in $\mathcal O_K$, $g$ must be a cubic polynomial. If Dedekend's theorem were to apply, then $2$ could not split completely, since any totally reducible cubic polynomial over $\mathbb F_2$ has a repeated root.

It follows that no such $\alpha$ can exist.

Comment: right, thank you very much!

Comment: That standard example was eventually added to the file (I don't remember when). One comment: the polynomial $x^3 + x^2 - 2x + 8$ is a bad choice because it's impossible to remember where the sign goes. The number $-\beta$ is a root of $-f(-x) = x^3 - x^2 - 2x - 8$, which is *far* easier to remember because every non-leading coefficient is negative.  Please use that polynomial when describing this field, not the one whose non-leading coefficients are sometimes positive and sometimes negative.